# How to add categories to wp_list_pages()

Tags: theme-development, navigation

What (if any) is the hook or method for including named categories into the wp_list_pages function?

The end result would be that the categories are added onto the end of the list of pages (along with any child categories that exist, with proper ul/li nesting for drop down css to act on)...

Home | About | Contact | Category 1 | Category 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't it be even easier to call `wp_nav_menu()` and customize your menu as you please from the admin menu?

Comment: This is realy better, with this solution you become a usefull markup and classes for set in stylesheet.

Comment: Probably so. I'll check out wp_nav_menu()

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of hooks in there (`wp_list_pages` is final output) and you can even pass your own [Walker Class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class) to it in `walker` argument. But I think this is going to be huge mess because of nesting and such.

Why don't just call [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories) right after it with similar markup and style both so they look alike?

Answer (score 0):

Install the following plugin :

http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/ (custom meta box)
This plugin will let you to create a checkbox list with customs categories values for your edit page.

I override the plugin from Tony Archambeau and implements a basic Walker class extended from Walker_Page (wp-includes/post-template.php l.977) and integrate a condition for my customs categories displayed as a class if they exist.
http://tonyarchambeau.com/blog/453-plugin-sitemap/ (generate a sitemap in a page thanks to a shortcode)

Here the source

```
http://pastebin.com/u7imhz0m
```

Hoping that it will help you.

Comment: `class WP_LIST_WALKER` is not a proper name for a custom class. Prepare for name collisions.